# Java Applet cannot run in CMD

Tags: java, applet, base64, japplet

I am trying to run an applet using `appletviewer` and I am getting the following Exception:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/appache/commons/codec/binary/Base64
```

I added the jar files in the classpath but I get again the error. In the compiler run perfect but in cmd don't.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a program which needs external jar files, from command prompt then only adding the files to your class path is not enough, you need to explicitly mention while compiling and executing the program that which jar files you want to include.

For the same you can use the following

**To compile**

```
javac -g -cp YOUR_JAR.jar YOUR_FILE_NAME.java
```

**To run**

```
java -cp YOUR_JAR.jar; YOUR_MAIN_CLASS
```

Here `-cp` flag is for `class path` and after this you need to write write the name of the jar file you need to include.